# the benefits of context and credentials

Tags: vue.js

I have a website for login and signup work, and I want to return the token from the backend, knowing that the backend is Nodejs , but I searched on the Internet for things related to returning a token and found this function where two variables were passed to this function. The first variable is Context and the variable The second is credentials, but I did not understand what I could benefit from these two variables or what each of the two variables crossed.
Can anyone tell me what to express each of the variables?

```
      retrieveToken(context,credentials){
        return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
            axios.post('/signin',{
                email: credentials.email,
                password: credentials.password
            })
            .then(response =>{
                const token = response.data.accessToken;
                // store our token 
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken' , token)
                context.commit('retrieveToken' , token) 
                resolve(response)
                console.log('The Response is:' , response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('some errors was happened:' , error)
                reject(error)
            })
    
        })
            }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is a Vuex action - Vuex will populate the `context` variable while you have to provide the `credentials` variable.

The `credentials` variable must be a plain JavaScript Object with 2 properties - `email` and `password`.

You will dispatch the action like this:

```js
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default
{
  data()
  {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  },
  methods:
  {
    ...mapActions(['retrieveToken']),
    myMethod()
    {
      this.retrieveToken({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more ?
I don't understand.

Comment: https://github.com/drehimself/todo-vue/tree/10-vue-auth